# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null and ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: angular, angular10

```
*<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="data_client2.length>0"> <button class="btn print" printSectionId="listVotantesPrint" ngxPrint i18n="@@downloadList"></button> '

<button class="btn csv ml-3" (click)="export('CSV', 'listVotantesPrint')"></button> 
 
<button class="btn excel ml-3" (click)="export('xls', 'listVotantesPrint')"></button> </div>
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------*
component.ts

```
 public export(type, element) {
    // console.log(element);
    this.exportAsConfig = {
      type: type, // the type you want to download
      elementIdOrContent: element, // the id of html/table element
    };
```

i am try to printing in csv and xml by button click but its giving me above error,
i don't why its telling me like this.can any one help me with this

i am using angular 9 "ngx-export-as": "^1.5.0",

Comment: I think the error is raised by another part of your application and not by the shown ones.

Comment: @SebastianS.    at Observable.push../node_modules/ngx-export-as/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (vendor.js:130230)

Comment: @SebastianS. i get this error in inspect

Answer (score 0):

double check that the element with id `listVotantesPrint` is an html table, csv format only works on tables